# Synchronous Counter

Tags: counter, verilog, synchronous

I'm trying to create a 32-bit synchronous counter using J-K flip-flops. I have a functional module for individual J-K flip-flops...

```
jkff(J, K, CLK, Q) where the first three are wire inputs and the last is a reg output.
```

I then have another functional module for the counter...

```
thirty_two(J, K, CLK, OUT[31:0]) where the first three are inputs and the last is output
```

In the thirty_two module, I instantiate many jkff modules, but I seem to be restricted to using wires as my output. Thus, OUT[31:0] is a wire instead of the desired reg I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you specify why you desire OUT[31:0] to be a `reg`? A `wire` being being driven `reg` should acceptable.

Comment: If you ask a question about the internals of `thirty_two` module, you need to show the relevant code. Why do you say that you are restricted to `wire`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake when starting out with verilog is thinking that wire & reg types have to match across hierarchy, they do not. A modules inputs are always wires and outputs can be regs or wires. Connectivity between modules are wires. The difference between usage of the two is purely down to how values are assigned or driven.

For example module thirty_two can use reg type to drive its output:

```
module thirty_two(
  output reg [31:0] OUT
);
  always @* begin
    OUT = 32'bx;
  end
endmodule
```

When instantiating thirty_two, outputs must drive wires. This make sense as the level that instantiates it can not directly change a sub modules output.

```
module top_level();
  wire [31:0] thirty_two_out;

  thirty_two thirty_two_i0 (
    .OUT( thirty_two_out )
  );
endmodule
```